# Python Create A Set Of Paths and Find Route Between Them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am hoping you guys can help me figure out what I am looking for. I am currently writing a program that transverses a series of menus and the program can in theory start and end from any of those menus and it needs to be able to figure out how to get from point A to point B but I am struggling to figure out terms I should be looking for to solve this problem.

Comment: The most basic algorithm for this is called Breadth-First Search. Take a look at it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: It may change to something else depending on your problem, but I think that for the use case you just explain, that would be it.

Comment: When you build the set of connections, that's called a "graph".  There are several Python modules designed for traversing graphs, including NetworkX and graph-tool.

Comment: Another well-known solution for this is "[Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm)". The Wikipedia lists a whole bunch of others on the "[shortest path problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)" page.

Comment: @TimRoberts it appears 'Graphs' was the term I was looking for. Once I added that to my searches I stumbled upon this article. Solved what I was trying to do. Thanks everyone!

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/building-an-undirected-graph-and-finding-shortest-path-using-dictionaries-in-python/